# Migration to Mobx 6: functional components aren't working with decorated observables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I faced with problem while migrating from Mobx 4 to Mobx 6.

I have a functional component but after updating Mobx it stopped working. Looks like store doesn't works. Component react on changes inside observable variable by `reaction` feature but changes aren't re-rendering. I made everything that was provided in [migration guide](https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html) but component's store doesn't working.

At some reason if I change functional component to class component everything starts working. But I really can't understand the reason why such happens and can't find any explanation of such behaviour.

Case looks like example bellow. Experimental decorators are enabled and any other stuff that was provided in Migration guide as well. So what is the reason of such behaviour and how can I implement **correct** logic in *functional* component?

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  info: {
    phone: string;
    email: string;
  };
}

const usersData: User[] = [
  {
    name: "Steve",
    age: 29,
    info: {
      phone: "+79011054333",
      email: "steve1991@gmail.com",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "George",
    age: 34,
    info: {
      phone: "+79283030322",
      email: "george_the_best_777@gmail.com",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Roger",
    age: 17,
    info: {
      phone: "+79034451202",
      email: "rodge_pirat_yohoho@gmail.com",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Maria",
    age: 22,
    info: {
      phone: "+79020114849",
      email: "bunnyrabbit013@gmail.com",
    },
  },
];

const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise<User[]>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(usersData);
    }, 2000);
  });
};
class Store {
  @observable users: User[] = [];

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }

  async init() {
    const users = await getUsers();
    this.setUsers(users);
  }

  @action setUsers(users: User[]) {
    this.users = users;
  }

  @action increaseUserAge(userIndex: number) {
    const users = this.users.map((u, k) => {
      if (k === userIndex) {
        u.age += 1;
      }
      return u;
    });
    this.setUsers(users);
  }

  @computed get usersCount(): number {
    return this.users.length;
  }
}

const store = new Store();

const UserList = observer(() => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    store.init();
  }, []);

  const addOneUser = () => {
    const user = {
      name: "Jesica",
      age: 18,
      info: {
        phone: "+79886492224",
        email: "jes3331@gmail.com",
      },
    };
    store.setUsers([...store.users, user]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Users: {store.usersCount}</h4>
      {store.users.length ? (
        <>
          <ul>
            {store.users.map((user, key) => (
              <li key={key}>
                Name: {user.name}, Age: {user.age}, Info:
                <div>
                  Phone: {user.info.phone}, Email: {user.info.email}
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => store.increaseUserAge(key)}>
                  Increase Age
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <button onClick={addOneUser} disabled={store.usersCount >= 5}>
            Add one user
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>Fetching users...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

function App() {
  return <UserList />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: why are you mixing `makeObservable` and decorators? Those are two different ways of working with mobx.

Comment: @IvanV. sorry, but you are wrong. https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html#upgrading-classes-to-use-makeobservable , p.2, quote:
`Leave all the decorators and call makeObservable(this) in the constructor. This will pick up the metadata generated by the decorators. This is the recommended way if you want to limit the impact of a MobX 6 migration.`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the option with the `decorators and `makeAutoObservable` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've made [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67076529-cugco) with your code (although removed types), it works fine.

Check `tsconfig.json` there, maybe you forgot to enable some of the options?

Or check what versions of `mobx` and `mobx-react` are you using?

And just a small nitpick on how you use your `increaseUserAge` action, it can be as simple as that:

```
  @action increaseUserAge(user) {
    user.age += 1;
  }
```

And in the jsx you just pass the whole user there:

```
<button onClick={() => store.increaseUserAge(user)}>
  Increase Age
</button>
```